# How to change the output of the method generated by Lombok's @ToString?

Tags: java, tostring, lombok

If we use Lombok's `@ToString`, for example as part of `@Data`, the output format is hard to read:

```
@Data
class Test {
    int a;
    int b;
}

Test test = new Test(1, 2);
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

This results in the following output:

```
a=1, b=2
```

Would it be possible to print it like this instead? If the structure of class is highly nested with maps and lists, it is really hard to read it.

```
a=1,
b=2
```

Comment: Seems easiest to write your own toString() method.

Comment: I don't think Lombok supports overriding the behavior of the toString method. Though if you would like something that then you might probably choose to override toString method for the class.

Comment: I would challenge whether it is even a good idea to pretty-print on multiple lines with `toString()`. Most people consider it a debugging tools, and it will show up in logs, and multi-line log entries are a bad idea in many environments. Note also that your need for display may vary in different parts of the program as well.

Answer (score 6):

Unfurttenly lombok doesn't come with that feature, however, is possible achieve it by using other libraries like **commons-lang3**.

***Decoupled solution***, class and serializer are not tied.

```
System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(test, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
```

***Coupled solution***

```
class Test {
    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }
}
```

call serializer:

```
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

Be aware that if you use this solution, could be conflict with @Data on ToString method, so to avoid that must use underhood(@Getter, @Setter, @RequiredArgsConstructor, ...) annotations instead os @Data.

Comment: The bottom paragraph is wrong. If your class has a `toString` method and is annotated with `@Data` then Lombok will not replace your explicit `toString`. There is no need to use `@Data`'s constituent annotations. The same is also true for all of Lombok's annotations. It will never replace code which you've written explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change the format of the text which is printed. See [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString).

The main goal of that annotation is to give you a quick and easy way to generate a method that you can use for logging etc. It's not designed to be all-purpose.

If you wanted to implement your own functionality across multiple classes, you could use aspect-oriented programming to accomplish that.

There's [an open ticket](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1297) to provide more control over the format but it's been open for a while and that doesn't seem likely to change any time soon. I think the desire to implement that feature is there but writing an implementation which works for everyone is tricky so they're proceeding with caution.